# Magmi products select all websites

Tags: magento, magmi

I'm using the MAGMI importer for Magento. I've got a multistore website with websites: base, store 1, store 2, store 3, store 4, etc.

I'm using this rule in my CSV file

```
"websites"
"base, store 1, store 2"
```

Unfortunately, after importing, all websites are selected (so store 3 and store 4 as well). Does anyone know a solution? I'm using MAGMI version v0.7.18

Comment: Please remove base from your CSV file, and try again.

Answer (score 2):

"websites" is obsolete, only use "store"

Comment: Great - this answer is correct. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes, here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_new_products